# E/ParseException: invalid session token

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a publicUser object to my Parse app. I create the _User with this:

```
//                  Creates the ParseUser
                    final ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                    user.setUsername(txtEmail);
                    user.setEmail(txtEmail);
                    user.setPassword(txtPassword);
                    user.put("publicUser",publicUser);
                    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback());
```

Now I have created a new _User with a pointer to publicUser - this works so far.
Then we'll go to the next activity, PublicUserActivity.

Here I make a ParseObject, publicUser, to get publicUsers object id from the pointer "publicUser":

```
final ParseObject publicUser = (ParseObject) ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("publicUser");
```

Then I try to get the ParseObject with a query:

```
//                Gets publicUser information
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("PublicUser");
                query.getInBackground(publicUser.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                        publicUser.put("firstname", txtFName);
                        publicUser.put("lastname", txtLName);
                        publicUser.put("_User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                        publicUser.saveInBackground();
```

It keeps throwing e with : E/ParseException: invalid session token

I think this should work, but i dont know what I am doing wrong? :(